# ora-12504 in Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, tnsnames, tns

I got `ora-12504:tns:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA` in Oracle Forms Builder but I can connect to same instance by SqlDeveloper!
What should change in Oracle Forms Builder?

Answer (score 2):

I think you (should) have an Windows environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` for your current user.

In your Windows' registry, probably have a key such as `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OH135135763]` which has two sub-key

- `FORMS_PATH` with value `C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_FRHome1\forms;`

  and
- `TNS_ADMIN` with value `C:\Oracle\Middleware\asinst_1\config`

  presumed.

Add `TNS_ADMIN`'s value at the end of the `FORMS_PATH`'s value as

- `C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_FRHome1\forms;C:\Oracle\Middleware\asinst_1\config`

and now you should be able to connect.

Or Problem may be related to your tnsnames.ora files' syntax, you may try the following one :

```
mydb=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myproddb)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = prddb.mycompany.com)
    )
  )
```

instead of

```
mydb=
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST= 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myproddb)(PORT = 1521))
       ) 
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = prddb.mycompany.com) 
     )
```

i.e. excluding `(CONNECT_DATA =` and including `(ADDRESS_LIST=` might be problematic.